# Is Sql Server 2008 R2 unsupported by Operations Manager (SCOM) 2007 R2?

Tags: configuration, installation, scom, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm performing a test configuration of System Center Operations Manager 2007 R2, on a system prepared with Sql Server 2008 R2. Unfortunately, the Scom 2007 R2 prerequisites verification program seems to be detecting exact versions of Sql Server, and not simply a minimum version, like it claims:

"System Center Operations Manager 2007 R2 requires SQL Server 2005 Standard or Enterprise Edition with SP1 and above or SQL Server 2008 Standard or Enterprise edition with SP1 **and above**. Note: Operations Manager 2007 R2 does not support a 32-bit Operations Manager Operations database, Reporting Server data warehouse or Audit Collection database on a 64-bit operating system."

I had hoped that this was just a helper tool that was assisting in getting me off the ground, but unfortunately it seems as if it's actually used as a gate for the installation to proceed. Has anyone encountered this? If so, is there a way to fool the installer into thinking that it has a proper version, or otherwise alert it to my valid configuration?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 is not an "update" to 2008; the requirements list 2005 or 2008 with certain Service Pack updates. It's simply not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably - remember SCOM 2007 R2 was released before 2008 R2.

Best bet is to contact Microsoft PSS and ask for a hotfix. Or at leatst contact them in the official forums. Or wait - probably a service pack will come soonish.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense considering Sql Server 2008 R2 was only released very recently. I'll post back when I get a response!

Answer (score 4):

On the SCOM installation disk there is a application that will allow you to create the databases, regardless of the pre-reqs.  You can find it at:

:\SupportTools\\DBCreateWizard.exe

Upon firing this up, you can choose whether you are creating a Operations Manager Database or a database for the warehouse.  For me, I left everything else as the default.  It created the database and I was able to return to my SCOM server and run the setup.

Answer (score 3):

Use of SQL Server 2008 R2 is currently only supported for new installations of Operations Manager 2007 R2. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2425714 for details.

Answer (score 3):

SQL 2008 R2 is now supported for migrations if you install SCOM 2007 R2 Cumulative Update 4.

KB Article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2449679/en-us

Download Link:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=39a871e0-d996-4568-be5d-2edb6f539330&displaylang=en

Upgrade Procedure (I think this will still be updated):
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789004.aspx